# VB6 Code to VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I have a problem translating VB6 To VB.NET i need this translated for the new functionality.

I've tried to translate VB6 code to VB.net but it failed maybe someone can help me out here

I don't know what `ReDim intKeyChars(1 To intKeyLen)` should look like the rest i think can be copy paste to VB.NET. VB6 behaves different from VB.NET in some cases.

```
  Public Function EnDecrypt( _
  ByVal strInputText As String, _
  ByRef strOutputText As String _
  ) As Boolean

On Error Resume Next
  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

  ' Private vars
  Dim intKeyChars()   As Long
  Dim intKeyChr       As Long
  Dim intKeyIndex     As Long
  Dim intKeyLen       As Long
  Dim intTextLen      As Long
  Dim intCounter      As Long
  Dim strInputKey     As String

  ' Set input key
  strInputKey = "TEST1290"

  ' Move key chars into an array of long to speed up code
  intTextLen = Len(strInputText)
  intKeyLen = Len(strInputKey)
  intKeyIndex = intKeyLen

  If (intKeyLen = 0) Or (intTextLen = 0) Then
    GoTo ErrorHandler
  End If

  ReDim intKeyChars(1 To intKeyLen)

  For intCounter = 1 To intKeyLen
    intKeyChars(intCounter) = Asc(Mid(strInputKey, intCounter, 1))
  Next intCounter

  For intCounter = 1 To intTextLen

    ' Get the next char in the password
    intKeyChr = intKeyChars(intKeyIndex)

    ' EnDecrypt one character in the string
    Mid(strInputText, intCounter, 1) = Chr(Asc(Mid(strInputText, intCounter, 1)) Xor intKeyChr)

    ' Modify the character in the password (avoid overflow)
    intKeyChars(intKeyIndex) = (intKeyChr + 32) Mod 126

    ' Prepare to use next char in the password
    intKeyIndex = (intKeyIndex Mod intKeyLen) + 1

  Next intCounter

  ' Return values
  strOutputText = strInputText
  EnDecrypt = True

  Exit Function

ErrorHandler:

  ' Return values
  strOutputText = vbNullString
  EnDecrypt = False

End Function
```

Comment: It's not impossible but you generally don't create arrays with a lower bound of anything but zero in VB.NET.  If you have 1-based arrays in VB6, change them to 0-based in VB.NET and change any code that indexes them accordingly.

Comment: It didnt work for me

Comment: If it didn't work then you did it wrong. Now, if you'd like us to tell what you did wrong, you're going to have to show us what you did. Keeping your code secret from those whom you want to help you is not the best course of action.

Comment: You are going to be fixing a bunch of off-by-one bugs in the translated code for the next couple of months.  Enjoy.

Comment: This function doesn't do anything! You have this: `strOutputText = strInputText` where `strInputText` was **never modified**. Only `intKeyChars()` array was changed, but it's not exposed outside the function. Further, nothing is ever "encrypted" here. This is at best a simple cypher, but in no circumstance is it real encryption. In converting this to .Net, look at the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace. Maybe recreate just the decryption routine from the old code so you can use it to update stored values using real encryption. What you have is just **begging** to get breached.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn `strInputText` **is modified** in the VB6 code. The `Mid()` statement in VB6 could be used to modify parts of a string: so `strInputText` is modified by this line  `Mid(strInputText, intCounter, 1) = ...`

Comment: Re lower bounds, it should be noted that .NET will technically support arbitrary lower bounds on any true `System.Array`.  However, one-dimensional arrays are not actually `System.Array` and bad things will happen if you try to pass a one-dimensional `System.Array` into any .NET thing that takes a vector.  So if you're tempted to try to use the .NET functions to make an array with a different lower bound, don't; it won't work.  (Insert rant against horrible design mistake in .NET that will never be fixed here.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's step through what the code actually does:

```
ReDim intKeyChars(1 To intKeyLen)
```

The ReDim keyword literally re-declares the *intKeyChars* variable where as the 1 to *intKeyLen* specifies that you want the bottom of the array to start at an index of 1 (which was common in legacy VB code) and the top of the array to end at an index of whatever the value of intKeyLen is.

There are some things that you'll need to adjust. Firstly, arrays cannot have an index of 1 in Visual Basic .NET, they must have an index of 0.

Secondly, the reason why legacy VB code used the ReDim statement to add items to an array was because there was no simple method of adding or removing items to a collection, you literally had to reallocate the memory and add or remove any values at that time. Luckily in Visual Basic .NET we have the [List(Of T) collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) that gives us built in methods such as Add, AddRange, Insert, Remove, RemoveAt, and RemoveRange. But after looking at the  code some more, the original legacy code should've just declare the array with the specified upper-bounds equal to the String's length in the first place (no need to ReDim the array each time).

So in your case, the updated code may look something like this:

```
Dim intKeyChars(strInputKey.Length - 1) As Integer
For intCounter As Integer = 0 To intKeyChars.Length - 1
    intKeyChars(intCounter) = Asc(strInputKey(intCounter))
Next
```

Comment: I'll go one step further... a method named `EnDecrypt()` probably doing _fake_ encryption, and that entire feature set should be refactored to use the classes in `System.Security.Cryptography`

Comment: Hand-migrating the code by rewriting individual routines in this way gives high quality code, but can be very time-consuming and therefore impractical if you have a large code base. There are third-party automatic conversion tools which will help cope with issues like arrays with non-zero lower bound.  I have (still) never actually used one, but I hear good things about them.

Comment: Disagree with the reason for the `ReDim` in VB6.  The reason is that the way VB managed variable declarations was a little quirky; even though you could declare a variable anywhere, it was generally as-if it was at the top of the routine, and there was no support for dynamic initialization.  Thus, if you wanted an array that was variable in size from call to call (even if it wouldn't change within the call), then you had to declare it without a size and then use `ReDim` to get to the size you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The ReDim statement can look like this:
`ReDim intKeyChars(intKeyLen)`

VB.NET arrays are always lower-bounded with zero, and thus ReDim only takes one parameter, the upper bound. Note that unlike C#, the upper bound index will be UBound(intKeyChars), not UBound(intKeyChars)-1, so the rest of the code should work. (intKeyChars element zero will be unused.)